# Are objects created in function destroyed after function execution?

Tags: javascript

This may be not typical question, because it's about Javascript, that MUST run under Windows 7 Widget engine, that uses old IE engine (don't remember how old).
What I'm trying to do is to make a list of some files from the harddrive. And this is working fine, but this is only the example for my question.

As you can see in the code, I'm creating an instances of ActiveXObject and Enumerator. Theoretically all these objects should be destroyed after this function execution, because all references kept in the function stack should be deleted. But it seems that this is not quite working this way here.

Why I think so? Because this widget working on machines that are on for weeks without restart and sidebar.exe process is eating more and more memory over time (function f_scanrec is running once per few days, and I'm sure it is not the other things that are growing, I spent on this months to figure it out). Without running this function, sidebar.exe have constant size in memory.

In Javascript I can't delete created objects manually. So, what can I do about this, how it exactly work here?

```
function f_scanrec(vS_path) {
    var vO_scanfs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var vO_dir = vO_scanfs.GetFolder(vS_path);
    var vO_enum = false;

    vO_enum = new Enumerator(vO_dir.SubFolders);
    for (; !vO_enum.atEnd(); vO_enum.moveNext()) {
        f_scanrec(vO_enum.item().Path);
    }
    vO_enum = new Enumerator(vO_dir.Files);
    for (; !vO_enum.atEnd(); vO_enum.moveNext()) {
/* Do something with this enumerator, but no more recursion calls */
    }
}
```

**Edit - found the solution**

After 4 months of testing the solution from the comment under this post, wrote by **Jaromanda X**:

*I would've said, yes, in this pattern of code, they would be GC'd ... but, then I read ActiveX - so, microsoft being microsoft, I'd say probably not, since, it's microsoft, and it's old old old microsoft "tech" that should've died 20 years ago, but hasn't :p*

And I answered:

*This ActiveXObject is created every function call. I move it outside this function. Now it is created once at widget launch and it's reference is stored in one global variable only. All seems to be working the same way as before so code work. Now I will see is that will help over time.*

And that was the solution. After almost two months of uninterrupted work with Windows 7 gadgets turned on, they still took about 130MB RAM! So the solution works!

Comment: I would've said, yes, in this pattern of code, they would be GC'd ... but, then I read `ActiveX` - so, microsoft being microsoft, I'd say probably not, since, it's microsoft, and it's old old old microsoft "tech" that should've died 20 years ago, but hasn't :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I think you hit the point! This ActiveXObject is created every function call. I move it outside this function. Now it is created once at widget launch  and it's reference is stored in one global variable only. All seems to be working the same way as before so code work. Now I will see is that will help over time.
Thank you so much to point me at possible problem :)
Greets :)